# Sphinx doesn't create index files in Windows

Tags: indexing, sphinx

search.conf file:

```
source app_main
{
    type        = pgsql
    sql_host    = localhost
    sql_user    = blizzard_moz455_1_3
    sql_pass    = adminpwd
    sql_db      = blizzard_moz455_1_3
    sql_port    = 5432

    sql_query   = \
    SELECT "id", "header", "date", "is_paid", "text", 10 as content_type\
    FROM app_main

    sql_query_info  = SELECT * FROM "app_main" WHERE "id" = $id
    sql_attr_uint   = content_type
    sql_attr_timestamp  = date
}

index app_main
{
    source       = app_main
    path             = D:/blizzard/Projects/Python/Web/moz455/app/sphinx
    docinfo      = extern
    morphology   = stem_enru
    min_word_len     = 2
    charset_type     = utf-8
    html_strip   = 1
    html_remove_elements = script
    min_prefix_len    = 0
    min_infix_len     = 3
    enable_star   = 1
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit = 32M
}

searchd
{
    listen = 127.0.0.1:3312
    log = searchd.log
    query_log = query.log
    read_timeout = 5
    max_children = 30
    pid_file = searchd.pid
    max_matches = 1000
}
```

Output of the command "indexer --config sphinx.conf --all":

```
using config file 'sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'app_main'...
collected 1 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 1 docs, 143 bytes
total 0.065 sec, 2172 bytes/sec, 15.19 docs/sec
total 2 reads, 0.000 sec, 2.5 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 9 writes, 0.000 sec, 1.2 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

I.e. no errors. But index files are not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"D:/blizzard/Projects/Python/Web/moz455/app/sphinx" isn't really a folder - last part ("sphinx") is a prefix to files. They were created in "app" folder: sphinx.spa, ..., sphinx.sps

Comment: You should makr your own answer as 'accepted' - will mark this question as answered, so others know.

Comment: I know, but it is possible only in two days after answering.